# Failing to simulate mouse click via Windows API

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I was dabbling with positioning of the mouse pointer which I had no trouble at all with, but trying to simulate a left click is giving me problems at the moment.

```
#include <Windows.h>
int main()
{
    SetCursorPos(100, 450);
    Sleep(3000);
    SetCursorPos(1600, 450);
    int n = 1;
    while (n <= 10); 
    {
        SetCursorPos(1600, 450);
        LeftClick();
        n++;
    }
}
```

My `LeftClick()` function is as follows:

```
void LeftClick()

//down
INPUT Input = {0};
Input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
::SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(INPUT));

//up
::ZeroMemory(&Input, sizeof(INPUT));
Input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
::SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(INPUT));
```

I've looked around and so far everything I've seen hasn't worked for me.
Please give me any help with anything to do with my sloppy code, not just how I am trying to simulate clicking,

Comment: Your `while` loop has an erroneous terminating `;` on it, so you get stuck in an endless loop and never call `LeftClick()` at all. Had you stepped into your code with a debugger, you would have seen that error in action. After you fix that, know that calling `SendInput()` with `nInputs=1` is almost always a logic bug. Send both down and up inputs in one call to `SendInput()`, not individually. And FYI, you can move the mouse with `SendInput()`, too. `SetCursorPos()` is immediate, but [`SendInput()` is delayed](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140213-00/?p=1773).

Comment: Thanks, worked fine without the while loop I'll be sure to start using the debugger and take further look into your tips. Thanks :D